# java.security.acl.Group does not exist in java17. How to use the alternative Policy that is mentioned in javadocs

Tags: java, security, acl, java-17, group

I'm getting the error below while compiling my old Java project using ant.

```
error: package java.security.acl does not exist
    [javac] import java.security.acl.Group;
```

I found that `java.security.Policy` is replacing Group that is removed. How do I make use of Policy in place of Group?
My usage is something like this :

```
Group g = (Group) JNDIUtils.lookup(context, dn);
```

I see no options available as an alternative

Comment: You must have some truly ancient code. The [Javadoc for *Java 1.8*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/acl/package-summary.html) says 'The classes and interfaces in this package have been superseded by classes in the java.security package. See that package and, for example, `java.security.Permission` for details'.

Comment: The code is ancient. checking some docs "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/acl/Group.html"
I see that Policy is replaced, but how that works as an alternative to Group - I'm not able to understand

Comment: So your entire usage is to declare a variable of that type and perform a single type cast?

Comment: @Holger Basically migrating from java8 to java11 - Group class has been removed completely. Need an alternative for that - as simple as that

Comment: There’s no method in the official API requiring a `Group` as input. There are, however, lots of methods accepting the superinterface, `Principal`. If you used one of those methods with a `Group`, you can use the same method with a `Principal`. Maybe, the documentation comment was a typo and should actually suggest to use `java.security.Principal` rather than `java.security.Policy`. However, without knowing what you actually want to do with the `Group` object, we can’t suggest alternatives, as we can’t know whether these alternatives would work with whatever you actually want to do with it.